# Expected getter method not found

Tags: objective-c, getter

I'm just learning Objective-C. I've got mistake on line

```
 int resultNumerator = numerator * f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator;
```

Can you help me?

```
#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}


-(void) print{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator:(int)n
{
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator:(int)d
{
    denominator = d;
}
-(void) add : (Fraction*)f
{
    // add two fractions
    // a/b + c/d = (a*d + b*c)/(b*d)

    Fraction *result = [Fraction new];
    int resultNumerator = numerator * f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with this:

```
int resultNumerator = numerator * f->denominator + denominator * f->numerator;
```

You defined fields not properties. In Objective-C to access property we use `.` and to access field we use `->` she we work with a pointer to a class instance.